# arrangement of word $ENGINEERING$ in which order of vowels remains unaltered

Tags: probability

> Letters of the word $ENGINEERING$ are arranged in a row at random. Let $p$ be the
>
> probability That the order of vowels remains unaltered, and $q$ be the probability that the order of
>
> consonants  remain unaltered, Then $p-q$ is

$\bf{Attempt:}$ Total arrangements $\displaystyle n(S) = \frac{11!}{3!\cdot 2!\cdot 3!\cdot 2!}$

Favourable cases

order of vowels remains unaltered

Given Vowels $E,I,E,E,I$

so we will select $5$ places out of $11$ for vowels  as $\displaystyle \binom{11}{5}\cdot $

So $\displaystyle n(A) = \binom{11}{5}\cdot \binom{6}{6}$

Could some help me how to solve it, Thanks

Comment: $p$ will be the number of ways of permuting the consonants - which will be $\frac{6!}{3!2!}$, because we have to account for the fact that there are actually $3$ indistinguishable $N$'s and $2$ indistinguishable $G$'s - divided by the total number of permutations of the letters, which will be $\frac{11!}{3!3!2!2!}$ - i.e., $p = \frac{6!3!3!2!2!}{11!3!2!}$. Compute $q$ similarly, and then take their difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a given arrangement of the letters of the word ENGINEERING, there are 
$$\binom{5}{3}\binom{2}{2} = 10$$
distinguishable ways to permute the vowels.  Only one of these arrangements leaves the relative order of the vowels intact.  Hence, the probability that the order of the vowels is preserved is 
$$p = \frac{1}{10}$$

In a given arrangements of the letters of the word ENGINEERING, there are 
$$\binom{6}{3}\binom{3}{2}\binom{1}{1} = 60$$
distinguishable ways to permute the consonants.  Only one of these arrangements leaves the relative order of the consonants intact.  Hence, the probability that the order of the consonants is preserved is 
$$q = \frac{1}{60}$$

Therefore, 
$$p - q = \frac{1}{10} - \frac{1}{60} = \frac{1}{12}$$

Answer (score 1):

@Chris is correct in the comment.

Here is the complete solution.

Given the word **ENGINEERING**.

Case 1: When Vowels are fixed.

You have 6 consonants to be permuted.

It can be done in $\dfrac{6!}{3!2!}$ ways (as said in the comment).

Therefore, the probability that the order of vowels is conserved is
$$p = \dfrac{6!}{3!2!} \times \dfrac{3!2!3!2!}{11!} = \dfrac{1}{4620}$$

Similarly, 'q' can be computed as:-

$$q = \dfrac{5!}{3!2!} \times \dfrac{3!2!3!2!}{11!} = \dfrac{1}{27720}$$

Hence, $p - q = \dfrac{231}{1280664}$

Comment: Your answer is incorrect.  For $p$, you need to multiply by the $\binom{11}{6}$ ways of placing the consonants.  For $q$, you need to multiply by the $\binom{11}{5}$ ways of placing the vowels.

Comment: Well, in that case, we will be "choosing" 6 consonants out of 11, which we are not for p. And so for q. But, thanks for your suggestions regarding the solution. I will work upon it and come back soon!

Comment: No.  We are choosing six positions for the consonants.  We then arrange the consonants in those positions in $\frac{6!}{3!2!}$ ways.  There is only one way to arrange the vowels in the remaining positions since they must appear in the order EIEEI.  What you calculated is the probability that the vowels are fixed in their original positions rather than the probability that the vowels appear in their original order.

Comment: Oh! You are correct! I forgot it was mentioned "order" and not position. Anyway, thank you!